# White Space when Subreport goes onto next page

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am stumped.  The below image is of one subreport that when it prints on all the same page is fine without any added white space; however, when the subreport extends to another page it creates a large white space before and after on the new page.  I've tried all the settings I can think of from shrink, keep together, etc., and I'm out of ideas.  There are no page breaks on the main report and no force new pages.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - I'm about to pull what little hair I have left out!

[image: Subreport Whitespace]

Comment: Would have to review report design. If you want to provide db I recommend Box.com fileshare site.

Comment: Happy to do that - I am at a loss where this white space is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying different things I figured it out.  Footer on the main report was set to 0.41" instead of 0.4" which was causing an issue with the margins.  I'm still not understanding why so much white space was generated before and after the report but after aligning the margins it's resolved.